# SQL - sum to multiple rows based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table like

```
id | value | date     | type
----------------------------
1  | 2     | 1.1.2016 | 1
----------------------------
2  | 6     | 2.1.2016 | 1
----------------------------
3  | 1     | 7.1.2016 | 1
----------------------------
4  | 10    | 3.1.2016 | 2
----------------------------
5  | 8     | 8.1.2016 | 1
```

I need to write a query, that gets the type 1 entries arranged so, that the entries that don't have a type 2 entry between them are summed on the same row. In my example, the query would return

```
sum | start    | end
-------------------------
8   | 1.1.2016 | 2.1.2016
-------------------------
9   | 7.1.2016 | 8.1.2016
```

Comment: what have you done so far?..

Comment: I don't understand your example. Shouldn't it be `9, '1.1.2016', '7.1.2016'` and `8, '8.1.2016', '8.1.2016'` ?

Comment: He wants it by date range, not id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify each group by counting the number of non-1 values before the row.  The rest is just aggregation:

```
select sum(value), min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when type <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where type = 1
group by grp;
```

Comment: This is a very elegant way to do it, and it also really performance minded. Though to get the grouping requested, I think it needs to be by date as in:
`SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY Date) Grp`
I also reversed the logic on the case, because I thought it read more cleanly.

Answer (score -1):

You can try `lead()` function like below query

```
select 
      value+lead_value as value, 
      date as start_date, 
      end_date
from(
    select *, 
           lead(value) over(order by id asc) lead_value, 
           lead(date) over(order by id asc) end_date, 
           ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by t order by id asc) row_num 
    from t1
    where type = 1)t2
where row_num % 2 = 1;
```

This gave me below result

[image]

Comment: Using this many window functions isn't as efficient for large sets.